# Stanford 4.0. Website Javadoc Link is Broken

Tags: stanford-nlp

The javadoc at this link: https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/

Returns a 403 error. I can get the javadoc from the download, but I use the online javadoc constantly. Would be nice to have it live again. :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'll fix this right now.

Comment: Ok it should be working again.

Comment: Please let me know if you run into any other issues.